# Website crashing due to too many entry processes

Tags: php, server, hosting

My website crashes randomly due to the entry processes maxing out, I could increase the amount I receive from my host but I don't believe I need to. I looked at the site visitors and I saw that the same IP had requested every single .php file within the public_html. It requested all these files at the same time, so i believe this is what is crashing my site. So my question is how do I stop all these files being loaded all the time.

Thanks Jamie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a firewall to limit the total request per ip. I use CSF on my servers

Comment: Can I do that through my server host? I'm using godaddy

Comment: Is it a dedicated server? If is a shared hosting, you can't